# RecyclerView data empty to display textview in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

My json data is empty to visible the textview and hide the recyclerview.
My xml code recyclerview and textview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="@dimen/common_padding"
>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/pending"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pendingnullorder"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Current no orders available"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="@dimen/order_list_view_font_size"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />
```

My java code show textview & hide recyclerview here:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View drawer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pending, container, false);

    pendingnullorder = (TextView) drawer.findViewById(R.id.pendingnullorder);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) drawer.findViewById(R.id.pending);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) drawer.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    orderLists = new ArrayList<>();

    getProgressData();

    adapter = new OrderListAdapter(orderLists, getActivity());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return recyclerView;
}
private void getProgressData(){
String token = SharedPreferencesManager.readPreferenceString("token", "D/N");
JSONObject progressData = new JSONObject();
try{
    progressData.put("token", token);
    JsonObjectRequest progressObject = new JsonObjectRequest(1, Common.OrderDetails + "progress", progressData, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject progressResponse) {
            Log.d("Responseprogress", progressResponse.toString());
            try {
                int status = progressResponse.getInt("status");
                if(status == 1) {
                    progressOrderProgress(progressResponse);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("Response", "PROGRESS ERROR");
        }
    });
    progressObject.setShouldCache(false);
    ServiceBellApp.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(progressObject);
}
catch (JSONException localJSONException){
    localJSONException.printStackTrace();
    return;
}}private void progressOrderProgress(JSONObject progressResponse) throws JSONException {
JSONArray result = progressResponse.getJSONArray("orderdata");
for(int i=0; i<result.length(); i++){
    OrderList orderListModule = new OrderList();
    JSONObject orderData = null;
    try {
        orderData = result.getJSONObject(i);
        orderListModule.setPackage_name(orderData.getString("name"));
        orderListModule.setOrderdate(orderData.getString("date"));
        orderListModule.setServicedate(orderData.getString("service"));
        orderListModule.setServicetime(orderData.getString("time"));
        orderListModule.setOrderid(orderData.getString("id"));
        orderListModule.setOrdstatus(orderData.getString("status"));
        orderListModule.setOrderamount(orderData.getInt("ramount"));
    }catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    orderLists.add(orderListModule);
}
swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();}
```

It's possible to any one help me.I am new in android code.

Comment: can you put your json response here !!

Comment: and also add pendingOrderProgress method

Comment: Check my updated code

Comment: i am waiting for your replay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your XML, you have set the visibility of your `TextView` `"pendingnullorder"` to `"gone"` and in the `onCreateView` method, you have also set the visibility of your `RecyclerView` `"pending"` to `View.GONE`. It seems you see none of your views.

In your method `getProgressData` (or `getPendingData`) you should change the visibility of one of this view depending on the size of your adapter (if no element: `pendingnullorder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`, otherwise: `recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`), and update visibilities on the `onResponse` method.

**[EDIT]**

Here is an example of what you can do:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View drawer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pending, container, false);

    pendingnullorder = (TextView) drawer.findViewById(R.id.pendingnullorder);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) drawer.findViewById(R.id.pending);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) drawer.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    /*recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);*/
    progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(inflater.getContext()));

    orderLists = new ArrayList<>();

    getPendingData();

    adapter = new OrderListAdapter(orderLists, inflater.getContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    updateUI();

    return drawer;
}

private void getPendingData() {
    String token = SharedPreferencesManager.readPreferenceString("token", "D/N");
    JSONObject progressData = new JSONObject();
    try{
        progressData.put("token", token);
        JsonObjectRequest progressObject = new JsonObjectRequest(1, Common.OrderDetails + "progress", progressData, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject progressResponse) {
                Log.d("Responseprogress", progressResponse.toString());
                try {
                    int status = progressResponse.getInt("status");
                    if(status == 1) {
                        progressOrderProgress(progressResponse);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("Response", "PROGRESS ERROR");
            }
        });
        progressObject.setShouldCache(false);
        ServiceBellApp.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(progressObject);
    }
    catch (JSONException localJSONException){
        localJSONException.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
}

private void progressOrderProgress(JSONObject progressResponse) throws JSONException {
    JSONArray result = progressResponse.getJSONArray("orderdata");
    for(int i=0; i<result.length(); i++){
        OrderList orderListModule = new OrderList();
        JSONObject orderData = null;
        try {
            orderData = result.getJSONObject(i);
            orderListModule.setPackage_name(orderData.getString("name"));
            orderListModule.setOrderdate(orderData.getString("date"));
            orderListModule.setServicedate(orderData.getString("service"));
            orderListModule.setServicetime(orderData.getString("time"));
            orderListModule.setOrderid(orderData.getString("id"));
            orderListModule.setOrdstatus(orderData.getString("status"));
            orderListModule.setOrderamount(orderData.getInt("ramount"));
        }catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        orderLists.add(orderListModule);
    }
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    updateUI();
}

private void updateUI() {
    if (adapter.getCount() == 0) {
        pendingnullorder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        pendingnullorder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give any coding for example

Comment: I have updated my answer, adding a method 'updateUI()' in your code and calling it 2 times (in onCreateView and in progressOrderProgress methods).

Comment: i tried your updated code that updateUI() function is not calling. i set log.d in updateUI() function, but no log displayed

Comment: You should at least have one log for the call in onCreateView. Also, is it correct that in this method you call "getPendingData", but you have not provided this method but this one: "getProgressData"?

Comment: Sorry getProgressData() is a getPendingData()

Comment: Ok, no problem. So you should rename "getProgressData()" with "getPendingData();" in my code.
But I cannot tell you what is your problem, it seems that you have a problem with your fragment since you don't even enter into "onCreateView".

Comment: log is displayed but textview not appear

Comment: Can you check what "adapter.getCount()" returns? It seems that it's something greater than 0. Also, I have just noticed that in onCreateView, you should do: "adapter = new OrderListAdapter(orderLists, inflater.getContext());", because you are not supposed to call "getActivity()" before "onActivityStarted()". I update the code in my answer.

Comment: I think it's because "adapter.getCount()" return a value greater than 0. Can you check it? Apart from that, I'm sorry but I made a mistake, you can call getActivity() in createView without problem.

Comment: It's k but I get getcount value 0

Comment: OK. In onCreateView, return your view "drawer" (the root view), not "recyclerView".

Answer (score 1):

1. First you need to check the data is not empty.
2. Second we can optimize the way to show the data for RecycleView. 
   Remove

   `adapter = new OrderListAdapter(orderLists, getActivity());`
   `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);`

in the `onCreateView` method. In `progressOrderProgress` method, please do as below

```
   if(adapter==null){
        adapter = new OrderListAdapter(orderLists, getActivity());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
   } else {
        adapter.updateData(orderLists); // please define this method in your adapter
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
```

Hope it will resolve your issue